# Modify secondary receiver amount in paypal adeptive ExecutePayment call

Tags: php, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained, delay

I've already implemented Paypal Adeptive (Delayed Chained Payment) and it is working quite well.

I've first called "Pay" to receive payment from customer(preapproved) into my business account and than in next event I called "ExecutePayment" to pay secondary receiver(preapproved)

My question is that "Can I change amount in ExecutePayment method to pay less or more to secondary receiver, or it is not possible to change amount" ?

Comment: Hi @Sanjay, did you found your answer to this?